# missing expression...?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am recently learning Oracle... and I am not sure why the following code returns me 'ORA-00921: unexpected end of SQL command' all my parentheses are closed and I also have the semicolon at the end. I am not sure what I am missing.

```
select animal_id, animal_type, name
from animal_outs
where sex_upon_outcome not like 'Intact %'
and animal_id = (select animal_id 
                 from animal_ins
                 where sex_upon_intake like ('Intact %');
```

Comment: Remove the `(` from `('Intact %')`

Comment: When you run into problems like this, count the `(` and the `)`. Same number?

Comment: "all my parentheses are closed" If you count again, you will find that they are not all closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Unexpected end" is due to missing closing bracket.

Also, consider using `IN` instead of `=` if subquery returns more than a single value (I guess it might), as you'd get `too_many_rows error`.

```
SELECT animal_id, animal_type, name
  FROM animal_outs
 WHERE     sex_upon_outcome NOT LIKE 'Intact %'
       AND animal_id IN (SELECT animal_id                            --> IN
                           FROM animal_ins
                          WHERE sex_upon_intake LIKE ('Intact %'));  --> closing bracket
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing extra paranthesis in the end. Modified query is:

```sql
select animal_id, animal_type, name
from animal_outs
where sex_upon_outcome not like 'Intact %'
and animal_id = (select animal_id 
                 from animal_ins
                 where sex_upon_intake like ('Intact %'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use in with like.

```
select animal_id, animal_type, name
    from animal_outs
    where sex_upon_outcome not like 'Intact %'
    and animal_id = (select animal_id 
                     from animal_ins
                     where sex_upon_intake like ('Intact %'));
```

Though better option would be:

```
select animal_id, animal_type, name
    from animal_outs 
    where sex_upon_outcome not like 'Intact %'
    and exists (select animal_id 
                     from animal_ins
                     where sex_upon_intake like ('Intact %') and animal_outs.animal_id = animal_ins.animal_id);
```